# Different on focus highlight sizes in "Want updates to your inbox?" blog section

Tags: bug, design, blog

One of the three buttons under the section titled ["Want updates to your inbox?"](https://stackoverflow.blog/) has a different highlight height on focus. (Screenshot collated to show differences side-by-side).

[image]

Using Windows 10, Firefox 101.0.1 (64-bit)